# Сочетание однородных членов

Tags: предложение

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, возможно ли такое написание: "Коттедж имеет большую кухню, просторную спальню и напольные часы в гостиной комнате"? Или подобное сочетание однородных членов будет ошибочным, вроде: "У него был свой дом, машина и голубые глаза".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, мне тоже однородные члены не нравятся,вернее, сочетание "коттедж имеет напольные часы".

Если "У него был свой дом, машина и голубые глаза" - риторическая фигура, то данная фраза на фигуру не тянет, это просто ошибка. Лучше написать "В коттедже имеются большая кухня и  просторная спальня, в гостиной находятся напольные часы " .

Comment: Спасибо! А что Вы скажите по поводу этого варианта: "Это был прекрасный коттедж с большой кухней, с просторной спальней и с напольными часами в гостиной комнате"? Тоже не вполне удачен?

Comment: По-моему, нормальный вариант.

Comment: А то, что первые два перечисленных пункта - помещения (кухня спальня), а третий пункт - предмет (часы) не искажает предложение? Не уверена, что правильно выразилась, но, думаю, Вы меня поняли.

Comment: Всё сглаживает добавочка "в гостиной комнате"

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Семантика предложения не очень ясна. Во-первых, описание больше соответствует неплохой квартире, а не прекрасному коттеджу. Во-вторых, идею просторных помещений как-то не очень понятно дополняет информация о часах. Почему внимание привлекли именно часы - эту мысль лучше изложить отдельно.

Comment: Не *гостиная комната*, а просто гостиная. И про семантику: даже в 30 кв. метров — это нормальная кухня для коттеджа. И семь спален с санузлами... Среди которых напольные часы вообще бы потерялись, особенно в коттедже прекрасном... 

Это реальное предложение или задание по составлению текста для среднего школьного возраста?

Comment: Это не реальное предложение, это не задание для учеников средней школы. И, представьте себе, даже не упражнение для детей дошкольного возраста. Это просто попытка понять какие члены сочетаются, а какие нет. Понятно, что предложение, где речь идет о машине и голубых глазах ошибочно. А вот если речь будет идти об описании дома, где сначала будут описаны помещения, а потом предметы интерьера, вот такое сочетание будет ошибочным?.. Мне стало интересно, и я просто привела первый пришедший в голову пример. Использовать его я нигде не собираюсь. Просто хотелось разобраться в правилах сочетания.

Comment: Ммарина, я думаю, что изучать особенности нашей грамматики лучше не на учебных и придуманных, а на реальных примерах. Если таких нет под рукой, то лучше смоделировать ситуацию. Например, вы живете в обычной квартире и случайно попадаете в коттедж. Что поразит ваше воображение, о чем вы могли бы рассказать потом  друзьям из своего круга. Или другая ситуация: вы тоже живете в коттедже и приходите в гости к своим друзьям. Только в этом случае вы можете сказать: "О, у тебя прекрасный коттедж. Большой  бассейн, картинная галерея!"

Comment: > Понятно, что предложение, где речь идет о машине и голубых глазах ошибочно.

Предложение, где речь идет о машине и голубых глазах, не ошибочно. Как здесь уже было отмечено, нарушение норм языка (более компетентные участники объяснят Вам, каких именно) в нем может быть намеренным. Другой пример креативного подбора компонентов ряда однородных членов: "Студенты всегда хотят три вещи: есть, спать и денег".